# How to tunnel RTMP through HTTPS in openmeeting?

Tags: openmeetings, rtmps

I have deployed openmeeting(4.0.4) on Linux server, which has only port 443 open on which nginx is running. I configure nginx to access open meeting web interface over https, but audio functionality is not working.

I want to implement tunning of simple RTMP over HTTPs. Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

**NOTE:** On server open meeting is running on http://localhost:5080